# orgmode : agenda AND todo-list on the same buffer (and restricted to current buffer)

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want to have in an unique buffer with agenda and todo list, and only for the current buffer (not for all my org mode files).

I found how to define two functions (org-agenda-list-current-file and org-todo-list-current-file) but I cannot manage to write a function calling both agenda and todo-list.

Thanks in advance.

```
;; org-agenda-current-file : agenda for current buffer 
(defun org-agenda-list-current-file (&optional arg)
  "org-agenda-list, but using only the current buffer's file."
  (let ((org-agenda-files (list (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))))
    (if (null (car org-agenda-files))
        (error "%s is not visiting a file" (buffer-name (current-buffer)))
      (org-agenda-list arg))))

;; org-todo-list-current-file : todo list for current buffer 
(defun org-todo-list-current-file (&optional arg)
  "`org-todo-list', but using only the current buffer's file."
  (let ((org-agenda-files (list (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))))
    (if (null (car org-agenda-files))
        (error "%s is not visiting a file" (buffer-name (current-buffer)))
      (org-todo-list arg))))


;; org-agenda-and-todo-list
    ;;  ???

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(
        ("a" "calendar" org-agenda-list-current-file )
        ("t" "todo" org-todo-list-current-file )
        ("z" "calendar + todo" org-agenda-and-todo-list )
        ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easiest approach is to use two of Org-mode's existing features together.  Use a [block agenda](http://orgmode.org/manual/Block-agenda.html) to show the agenda and todo list together, like this:

```
(add-to-list
 'org-agenda-custom-commands
 '("z" "calendar + todo"
   ((agenda "")
    (todo ""))))
```

And then, when you open the agenda, [restrict to the current file](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-dispatcher.html) with the `<` key (so, if you have `org-agenda` bound to `C-c a`, do `C-c a < z` instead of just `C-c a z`).

It's probably possible to use your current approach, or in some other way remove the need for the `<` prefix here, but the Org-mode code is not exactly straightforward, so I haven't worked out exactly how yet.